# Retrieve keys from JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Json.net for a project and I need to get specific items (in that case "episode_key")  from an JArray. 
I use that way to do so, but I'm wondering if there is another way (slighter) :

foo is a JArray which a geted from : `var foo = data["foo"];`

```
for (int i=0; i < foo.Count(); i++) 
{
   TvProgram prog = new TvProgram { Key = foo[i]["episode_key"].ToString() }; // set the episode key
}
```

My json object look's like :

```
foo: [
{
episode_key: "32",
ddr_timeframes: [],
keywords: "",
synopsis: ""
},
{
episode_key: "542",
keywords: "",
synopsis: ""
}]
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found  a way to do so with linq :

```
var keys = from m in foo
           select m["episode_key"];
```

Regards